# Adding keys to an object inside readFile

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I'm learning my way through `node` and `gulp` and trying to do something that there may already be a solution for but I'm doing it as a learning exercise. The idea is that I want to scan all the files in a directory, read the files and look for the `gulp.task` line, read in the task name and the comment above it. This information will be used to generate an object then sent to a file in order to make something readable by [gulp-list](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-list).

I'm stuck trying to add items into the object during the reading of the file. Nothing I have tried so far enables me to add a key and value to the object.

Any help you can give would be great. Also if you know of another (potentially easier way) I would be really interested to hear. I've had a look at [gulp-task-list](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-task-list) but this does not seem to support the multiple file approach I want to use.

```
var gulp = require('gulp')
    fs = require('fs');

var path = './gulp/tasks';
var taskList = {};

// DESC: Rebuilds the list
gulp.task('build:list', function() {
    fs.readdir(path, function(err, files) {
        if (err) throw err;
        files.forEach(function (file) {
            fs.readFile(path+'/'+file, function(err, data) {
                if (err) throw err;
                lines = data.toString().split("\n");
                lines.forEach(function (item, index, array) {   
                    if (match = item.match(/^gulp\.task\(\'(.*)\'/)) {
                        console.log(match[1]);
                        taskList[match[1]] = true;
                    }
                })
            });
        })
    })
    console.log(taskList);
});
```

Comment: `fs.readdir()` and `fs.readFile()` are both async.

Comment: Yes I realise they are both async, does this mean that I cannot alter a variable outside of their scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution, I figured out that it's probably not possible to alter a variable out of scope while in an async function. I'm not entirely sure why but I am sure I will learn that over time unless anyone wants to point me in the right direction.

My solution, in full including writing out the JSON file

```
var gulp = require('gulp')
    fs = require('fs')
    gutil = require('gulp-util');

var path = './gulp/tasks';
var taskList = {};

// Rebuilds the task list
gulp.task('build:list', function() {
    files = fs.readdirSync(path);
    files.forEach(function (file) {
        var contents = fs.readFileSync(path+'/'+file);
        var lines = contents.toString().split("\n");
        lines.forEach(function (item, index, array) {   
            if (match = item.match(/^gulp\.task\(\'(.*?)\'/)) {
                taskList[match[1]] = array[index - 1];
            }
        })
    });
    fs.writeFileSync('./tasks.json', JSON.stringify(taskList));
    gutil.log("Task list built");
});
```

The second solution I thought of might be a lot easier, I thought maybe I can read each file and concat all of the files into a single file which then might be able to replace the `gulpfile.js` file which then might allow me to use another tool to get all the task names and descriptions. Or possibly concat the files together and then instead of process multiple file I can process one. If I come up with one of these solutions I will update this.